# Zend Router Logic

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I am struggling with how to handle my URL mapping. Right now, I am working on putting together a photo gallery system using the Zend Framework. The gallery system can handle categories and galleries. A category can have child categories or galleries in it. Obviously, a gallery has an image. This means I could have the following URL possibilities...

domain.com/gallery/ <== main gallery page

domain.com/gallery/category1/gallery1/ <==displays gallery of images

domain.com/gallery/category1/category2/ <== displays gallery of galleries

domain.com/gallery/category1/category2/gallery1 <== displays gallery of images

domain.com/gallery/category3/gallery2/image1 <== displays single image page

domain.com/gallery/gallery3/ <== disabled categories therefore it displays a gallery of images

How can I handle multiple options? If there was a simple task where it was always going to be /{category}/{gallery}/{image}/ then I could put it together. But I am struggling with how to manage it where the number of variables change.

If I run with the assumption that the each Gallery/Category/Image has a unique name meaning a gallery and category don't share the same name, then I can simply ignore all of the variables except the last one. I could set up a script that takes the last variable, compares it to the image table, the gallery table, and then the category table, and then forwards it to the correct view when the first variable gets a hit. While this sounds fairly resource intensive with possibly 3 model queries for each call to the gallery system, I can't fathom any other way to go about it.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions to do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url doesn't need to know the hierarchy of categories, IMO. If you agree and given that gallery is a controller you could solve it like this:

> domain.com/gallery/display/gallery/23
>   domain.com/gallery/display/category/42
>   domain.com/gallery/display/image/5

Which would mean you just have a display action and you pass the rest as params. In case you pass the param gallery, you show the gallery with the respective ID, in case you pass the param category, you check, if this category has subcategories and show them or the respective galleries.

You could also think of a solution where you have a gallery module, a display controller and gallery, category, image actions. In that case you would need to add an /id/ part in the url:

> domain.com/gallery/display/gallery/id/23

Let your model figure out the hierarchy and reflect it with breadcrumbs or similar.

Comment: That is easy enough.  I was trying to put the hierarchy in the URL for readability and SEO rather than practical scripting reasons...  Your right, doing it as you suggested is easy and in fact is what I am doing right now in development but was hoping to do something more.  I guess I could just do breadcrumbs for user navigation.

Comment: What would you win? I think readability is better the simple way and SEO won't improve either!?! The KISS principle seems to apply here!